# iOS Error: Assigning to NSMutableString from NSArray object (type 'void')?

Tags: objective-c, ios, string-concatenation, nsmutablestring

I just can't seem to resolve the error that comes up here: "Assigning to 'NSMutableString *__strong' from incompatible type 'void'".  The array string value I am trying to append is an NSArray constant.

```
NSMutableString *reportString     
reportString = [reportString appendString:[reportFieldNames objectAtIndex:index]];
```

Comment: Read the documentation, pretty please...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`appendString` is a `void` method; you are probably looking for

```
reportString = [NSMutableString string];
[reportString appendString:[reportFieldNames objectAtIndex:index]];
```

You can avoid `append` altogether by combining it with the initialization:

```
reportString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[reportFieldNames objectAtIndex:index]];
```

Note that there is another appending method of `NSString` that requires an assignment:

```
NSString *str = @"Hello";
str = [str stringByAppendingString:@", world!"];
```

Comment: Or you can do `NSMutableString *reportString = [reportFieldNames[index] mutableCopy];`.

Comment: Answer accepted for most information provided, meaning most helpful to all.

Answer (score 1):

appendString already appends a string to the string you're sending the message to:

```
[reportString appendString:[reportFieldNames objectAtIndex:index]];
```

That should be enough. Note that if you develop in Xcode 4.5, you can also do this:

```
[reportString appendString:reportFieldNames[index]];
```

Comment: Technically that's not a Xcode 4.5 tip, that's a "using the LLVM 4.1 compiler" tip. :)

Comment: @cmac lemme note that questions like this have nothing to do with Xcode. Xcode is just a nifty-gifty wrapper around Clang/GCC and the iOS SDK. Just an IDE. It ain't a compiler or a development in itself. One can easily write iOS apps without even opening Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSMutableString *reportString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[reportString appendString:[reportFieldNames objectAtIndex:index]];
```

Answer (score 0):

appendString is a void method. so:

```
NSMutableString *reportString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[reportString appendString:[reportFieldNames objectAtIndex:index]];
```

Answer (score 0):

The NSMutableString method `appendString:` doesn't return anything, so you can't assign its nonexistent return value. That's what the compiler is trying to tell you. You either want NSString and `stringByAppendingString:` or you want to just use `[reportString appendString:[reportFieldNames objectAtIndex:index]];` without assigning the return value.

(Of course, you will need to have created a string to go in `reportString` first, but I'm assuming you just left that out of your question for completeness.)